# No Internet with LAN Connection

Tags: windows-xp, networking, internet

I have a client's computer that is connected via CAT5 to our network.  It is receiving data back and forth (tested with ping), but there is no internet.  I was able to pull up a connection to our local server.  It is setup for a modem connection tethered to a cell phone.  I have checked the TCP/IP settings and its setup for DHCP (like it should be), I've tried resetting the Internet Options, done a WINSOCK fix and nothing seems to be working.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is a "WINSOCK fix"?

Comment: What can you ping? Whats the difference between this client's computer and your own? Is yours a member of a domain?

Comment: Winsock fix is vb applet that tunnels your internet connection.

And I was able to ping google.com and the local server.  Google is domian exclusive, and my server is domain inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Did DHCP pull down the DNS server settings?  What error are you getting?  If you go to 74.125.45.100 (google.com) does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're able to ping devices outside of your network, check to make sure your proxy and DNS settings are what are supposed to be.

Comment: Proxy was probably covered when he reset internet options.. And DNS when he checked TCP/IP settings

Comment: Yes, and check on that.  Still no good.